# Use Python file as a Namespace

Tags: python, class, namespaces, function-definition

I've encountered a problem with what seems to be trivial.

If we define such a structure in a python file:

```
class A:
   pass

class B:
   a = A()
```

We cannot define it the other way around:

```
class B:
   a = A  # <-- the error is here

class A:
   pass
```

The compiler says `a = A` is an unresolved reference, but we do it in `java` for example, it's okay, and it will compile.

It's not a big deal, however I'm wondering about the actual logic behind this. This looks as if it wasn't a complicated structure, but a script, which initializes classes one by one instead of analyzing it.

Can a `python` file be converted to a namespace, similarly to functions inside a class, which are aware of their existence, regardless of the sequence of their definition?

Comment: In your error case: `a = A` is evaluated immediately, as it is a class attribute. At that moment the **interpreter** hasn't created `class A` yet, that's why you get the error.

Comment: When `a = A` gets executed, Python will use the object `A` refers to at this moment. You define a class `A` later in your code, but there's no guarantee that the name `A` won't refer to some other object at some point during the execution of your script. So, the only logical thing is to use the current value, and raise an error if none has been given yet.

Comment: Python is not Java. Although note, in Python, *the code compiles* as well. The problem is that in Python, class bodies are just like any other part of code, they are executed, and the body is used as the namespace for the class (you can think about it as syntactic sugar for a call to the class (type) object constructor, `type(name, (parents,), namespace)`

Comment: "Can a python file be converted to a namespace" a module already acts a namespace. I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: How can I reference class A from class B, given that class B was defined EARLIER in the code? The same as in my example.

Comment: @winwin, you can define `a` as an instance variable of `B` rather than as a class variable, but this fundamentally changes the relationship between the two

Comment: @MichaelRuth so there is basically no way in python to do this to a class variable?

Comment: @winwin, no. As others have said, class variable definitions are executed immediately so `A` must be defined before `B`. Question: why can't you make `a` an instance variable of `B`, i.e. define `a` within `B`'s `__init__()`?

Comment: To be precise, you cannot do it in the *class definition statement body* if the class B definition comes first. You *can* always do `B.a = A()` after you define `A`, if you insist on defining your classes in this order